# How many connections are possible? (Graph-riddle)

Tags: graph, nodes, combinations

I got a little riddle concerning graphs.

In this case it is forbidden that 3 nodes are directly connected to each other. In other words, you cannot create 3 connections between 3 nodes which would create a triangle (each corner is a node and the edges are the connections)

Prove that the biggest possible amount of connections is n² when we got 2*n nodes. Also prove that this condition is realizable for each n.

n is part of the positive natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in part, one can prove that the number `n*n` is realizable can be solved by the following proof sketch, where induction on `n` is used. For `n=0` the graph is empty, for `n=1` the graph is a straight line and for `n=2` the graph is a square. For the induction step, let `n` be arbitrary such that there is a graph with `2n` nodes which has `n*n` edges and is triangle free. To understand the idea of the proof, imagine the graph arranged in two rows of `n` nodes each. Add two nodes as a column right to this graph, creating a graph with `n+2=2(n+1)` nodes. Connect these nodes to each other, creating `1` new edge.

Connect the upper new node to the columns left of it, alternating between upper and lower row, starting in the upper row. This creates `n` edges. Likewise, connect the lower new node to the columns left of it, alternating between upper and lower row, starting in the upper row. This creates `n` edges. In total, the construction does not create a triangle.

In total, `2*n+1` new edges were created. In total, the graph has `n*n+2*n+1=2*(n+1)` edges, which is the desired amount.